# Spring NamedNativeQuery error: "No query defined for that name"

Tags: java, spring-data, named-query

I'm trying to use a NamedNativeQuery from Spring data and getting the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name
> [test]

**My Query:**

```
package com.test.domain;

import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;

@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = TestNativeNamedQuery.FIND_QUERY_NAME,
        query= "SELECT id, name FROM table_test",
        resultClass = TestNativeNamedQuery.class )
public class TestNativeNamedQuery {
    public static final String FIND_QUERY_NAME = "test";
    Integer id;
    String name;
    // getters and setters
}
```

**Query runner:**

```
package com.test.service;

@Service
public class TestService {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    
    public ResponseEntity run() {       
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery(
                TestNativeNamedQuery.FIND_QUERY_NAME, TestNativeNamedQuery.class);
                
            List result = query.getResultList();        
    }       
}
```

**Spring App Configuration:**

```
package com.test;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.test"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(basePackages = {"com.test"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.test"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.test.domain"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ccn you try replacing references from `TestNativeNamedQuery.FIND_QUERY_NAME` with "test" i think this is compile info which is need for annotation processing

Comment: I tested and same error

Comment: Can you include the packages that each of these classes are all in, in the above blocks?

Comment: @Atmas I did it.

Comment: Do you have a JpaRepository defind for your TestNativeNamedQuery domain class?

Comment: I ask because just looking at the doc it seems like it's part of their section on Annotation-based Configuration. Their example is for a NamedQuery (non-native) but I suspect the binding mechanism to locate/execute it would be the same. Maybe you have t o prefix the actual name of your query with your domain class name accordingly (i.e. they show User.xyz). Here's the site I'm referring to: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries - Under section "Example 6. Annotation-based named query configuration"

Comment: I think that is really the problem. I will use jdbcTemplate because I dont have a jpaRepository and I'm not getting any Entity. Thanks